# Specific Scrolling behaviour of a div

Tags: html, css, animation, scroll, behavior

Did anyone noticed the scrolling behaviour of twitter website, [image]

in this website the rightmost div stop scrolling , when it's over but the middle one continues scrolling , i want this behaviour on my website but not been able to do so please hel!! here is my starting code

```
    .parent {
        display: flex;
        flex-direction: row;
        align-items: flex-start;
        position: static;
        top: 0;
    }
    .parent > * {
        width: 100%;
    }
    .child1 {
        background: tomato;
        border: 10px solid green;
        height: 5000vh;
    }

    .child2 {
        height : 500vh;
        border: 10px solid pink;
        position: sticky;
        background: skyblue;
        color: white;
        top: 0;
        bottom: auto;
    }

<div class="parent">
    <div class="child1"></div>
    <div class="child2"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you mean? Using `overflow:scroll;` can achieve this.

```css
.scroll{
  background:red;
  width:200px;
  height:100px;
  overflow:scroll;
}
```

```html
<div class="scroll">
  <br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>
</div>
<br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>
```